# jQuery add <li> to <ul> containing button for each <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm creating a simple CRUD web application.

I want to be able to enter a search string and match the search string to possible matching items. In this case, i search by Product.Name.

I have the following JS code:

```
function findByName() {
    var id = $('#prodName').val();
    var url = "api/product/GetProductsByName/" + id
    //$.getJSON(uri + '/' + name)

    $.getJSON(url)
        .done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#searchedProducts'));
            });
        })
      .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
          $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
      });
}
function formatItem(item) {
    return item.Name + ' | ' + 
    item.Category + ': $' + 
    item.Price;
}
```

Which works fine for adding lines of the Product i search for.

However I also want to implement the "Update" functionality by adding a button next to each item in the row reading "Edit"

I know that I can use jQuery to generate li items dynamically, but how do I add buttons to each li item? And also keep a reference for each button to the appropriate item in the ul?

EDIT:

I would like the list to look something like this:

```
item1 (button)
item2 (button)
item3 (button)
item4 (button)
```

Comment: store the product id/any unique identifier as attribute of li or the item, and simply add button tags while creating list and on click of any button find next or closest() product item and get the attribute value to do edit operation.

Comment: Yes, prefect. How do I dynamically add the button element to each li item?

Comment: Same you have already done it,, just a sample use to refactor
$.each(['pro','prd2','pr3'],function(idx,item){$('div').append("<li id="+itemName/id+">"+asdf+"</li><button>"+edit+"</button>)})})